# Laravel query count total rows

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query:

```
$counts = DB::table('projects')
    ->join('prject_links', 'prject_links.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
    ->join('links', 'links.id', '=', 'prject_links.link_id')
    ->join('segments', 'segments.id', '=', 'links.segment_id')
    ->join('hthree_regions', 'hthree_regions.id', '=', 'segments.hthree_id')
    ->join('areas', 'areas.id', '=', 'hthree_regions.area_id')
    ->join('zone_regions', 'zone_regions.id', '=', 'areas.zone_id')
    ->select(
        'zone_regions.id as regions',
        'areas.id as provinces',
        'hthree_regions.id as cities',
        'segments.id as segments'
    )
    ->get();
```

what I'm looking to have as result is something like:

```
counts => [
  regions => 20,
  provinces => 10,
  cities => 7,
  segments => 5
];
```

What do i get currently is confusing result like:

[image: one]

**any idea about how to fix my query?**

Comment: Have you tried to add some `groupBy()`?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert no i haven't

Comment: this will be result https://ibb.co/sQFKx2z `->groupBy('projects.id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy` and `count(distinct field)` to get the field's count in each project:

```php
->selectRaw(
        "CONCAT('project ', projects.id) as project, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT zone_regions.id) as regions,
         COUNT(DISTINCT areas.id) as provinces,
         COUNT(DISTINCT hthree_regions.id) as cities,
         COUNT(DISTINCT segments.id) as segments"
    )
->groupBy('projects.id')
->get();
```

Comment: it says `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: thanks error is gone, may i ask how can i add projects into this result? let say `[project: project 1, cities: 5, ....]`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert why sum? i need count only i guess, let say i will get `project 1 has 5 cities, project 2 has 17 cities` etc.

Comment: @mafortis I have add attribute `project id` for each project

Comment: yes i'm trying it now, i think you should use `projects` instead of `project`

Comment: if i want to have full data of joined table in this result it's possible? let say right now we have `project: project 1, cities: 5, etc.` also having project,links like `project: project 1, links: [...], cities:5, etc.`?

Comment: @mafortis because you are using query-builder, you can get the links by group_concat, it will return string, and you need to loop each project to `explode(',', links)`, convert string to array.

Comment: i should add `explode(',', links)` under `->groupBy('projects.id')`?

Comment: @mafortis, try `->selectRaw(
        "CONCAT('project ', projects.id) as project,  GROUP_CONCAT(links.id),
         COUNT(DISTINCT zone_regions.id) as regions,
         COUNT(DISTINCT areas.id) as provinces,
         COUNT(DISTINCT hthree_regions.id) as cities,
         COUNT(DISTINCT segments.id) as segments"
    )` and the attribute links will be string. you need to convert it to array.

Comment: hmmm, this just return links id's not full data of links `results` `GROUP_CONCAT(links.id): "4,6"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212592/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

This might be your solution. Run it and let me know if that helps

```php
$counts = DB::table('projects')
    ->join('prject_links', 'prject_links.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
    ->join('links', 'links.id', '=', 'prject_links.link_id')
    ->join('segments', 'segments.id', '=', 'links.segment_id')
    ->join('hthree_regions', 'hthree_regions.id', '=', 'segments.hthree_id')
    ->join('areas', 'areas.id', '=', 'hthree_regions.area_id')
    ->join('zone_regions', 'zone_regions.id', '=', 'areas.zone_id')
    ->groupBy('projects.id')
    ->selectRaw(
        'count(zone_regions.id) as regions',
        'count(areas.id) as provinces',
        'count(hthree_regions.id) as cities',
        'count(segments.id) as segments'
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: it says `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: You can put all your `selectRaw` arguments inside an array

Comment: Just wrap it with [ 'count(zone_regions.id) as regions',
        'count(areas.id) as provinces',
        'count(hthree_regions.id) as cities',
        'count(segments.id) as segments' ]

Comment: add [ ] brackets in selectRaw